# Samba share not working with AD Groups

Tags: samba, sharing, active-directory

I am new to linux and samba world
i created a windows AD and added to this AD ubuntu machine.
what i want to do its to create a share folder using samba and to group from AD to get permission to this folder 
i not able to do it 
can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

try this code using terminal

```
sudo mount.cifs -o username=(windows user name) //(Windows PC IP)/(Windows share folder name) /(Ubuntu share folder path)
```

after that it will ask sudo password and then User password. for User Password you have to type Windows PC User password. and it will mount Windows shared folder in to your Ubuntu Shared folder. after that if you need to un-mount the shared folder you can follow

```
sudo umount -a -t cifs
```

code and it will un-mount windows shared folder from ubuntu folder. if it fails try

```
sudo umount -a -t cifs -1
```